# Get orders of a specific customer woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to get the orders of a specific customer based on their ID, no matter what the current status of order is, I just want to retrieve it.
I'm trying with the below method, but it always returns empty array.
I already made sure that this customer have some orders with `completed` status.

```
function getOrderOfUser(){
    $orders=wc_get_orders(array(
//      'customer_id'=>22,
        'status'=>'completed'
    ));
//  var_dump($orders);
    return $orders;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using wordpress [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) instead

```
$user_id = 22;
$orders  = get_posts( array(
  'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
  'meta_value'  => $user_id,
  'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
  'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
  'numberposts' => -1
));

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $orders );
echo '</pre>';
```